Как можно обучить бота определенному диалогу
Через что можно обучить обучить бота определенному диалогу? Взять скормить какой-нибудь текст и потом задавать вопросы ему и он бы отвечал?
Есть какие-нибудь модели чтобы взять ее поднять у себя, обучить, а потом уже использовать?
В какую сторону мне стоит посмотреть?

LLAMA, RAG, finetune обучить модель с нуля очень дорого.  для понимания текущего положения и ваших возможностей, посмотрите сюда https://github.com/karpathy/llm.c
